# MongoDB count object fields based on condition

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

Suppuse I have the documents:

```
{
  "X": {
    "Y": {
      "a": true,
      "b": false,
      "c": true
    }
  }
}

{
  "X": {
    "Y": {
      "a": true,
      "b": false,
    }
  }
}
```

I want to return the number of `true` fields in `Y` like this:

```
{
  "X": {
    "Y": 2
  }
}

{
  "X": {
    "Y": 1
  }
}
```

The number of `Y` fields aren't necessarily the same in each document and some documents contain no `Y` at all. How can I achieve this using the aggregation framework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Project Array Document Size with Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952230/mongodb-project-array-document-size-with-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "X.Y": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": { "$ifNull": ["$X.Y", { "Y": {} }] }
          },
          "as": "d",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$d.v", true] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N_yTNoQLqYK)

Comment: With this solution, what happens if a document does not contain `Y`?

Comment: I'm suspecting this error happens when `Y` isn't present (error: `"The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"`).