# Get all documents from collection every x document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bigdata

I have some data in collection **Logs** with about 85M documents like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:29:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:25:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:20:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:16:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 2,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:29:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 3,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:25:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:11:49.000Z')
},
...
```

How can i get all data of **id=1** with every xxx documents for charts like below:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:29:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:20:49.000Z')
},
{
    id: 1,
    ....,
    timestamp: ISODate('2020-04-24T11:11:49.000Z')
},
```

I had try use *$group* but not match exactly.
Had use [$map and $range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952230/mongodb-project-array-document-size-with-condition) but not successful.

I had try

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {$match : {"id" : 1}},
    {$sort: {"timestamp":-1}},
    {$group : {'_id' : "$id",'docs' : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
    {$project : {
        "list" : {
          $map : {
            'input' : {$range : [0, {$size : '$docs'}, 3]}, #3 is x-step
            'as' : "index",
            'in' : {$arrayElemAt : ['$docs', '$$index']}
          }
    }}}
], {allowDiskUse:true})
```

but i get error `"errmsg" : "$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes"`

Thanks for support.

Comment: what do you mean by *with every xxx documents* ?

Comment: @whoami I wish get data at [0, x, x+x, .... x*n]

Comment: You could use $group with $reduce.  Depending on what you are intending to do, [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html#sample-aggregation) may be useful as well.

Comment: @Joe I want get exactly data at positions in  [0, x, x+x, .... x*n] from newest date

Comment: so $group with $reduce is probably the way to go then

Comment: @Joe your way is use group by id then $push all docs to array => use $reduce in $project to filter result?